# Understanding a typical output from a geotiff file

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotag

A typical output from geotiflib mey look like this:

```
Geotiff_Information:
    Version: 1
    Key_Revision: 1.0
    Tagged_Information:
       ModelTiepointTag (2,3):
          0                0                0
          1547250          5415950          0
       ModelPixelScaleTag (1,3):
          100              100              0
       End_Of_Tags.
    Keyed_Information:
      GTModelTypeGeoKey (Short,1): ModelTypeProjected
      GTRasterTypeGeoKey (Short,1): RasterPixelIsArea
      GeographicTypeGeoKey (Short,1): GCS_DHDN
      GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Angular_Degree
      GeogEllipsoidGeoKey (Short,1): Ellipse_Bessel_1841
      GeogSemiMajorAxisGeoKey (Double,1): 6377397.16
      GeogSemiMinorAxisGeoKey (Double,1): 6356078.96
      GeogInvFlatteningGeoKey (Double,1): 299.152813
      ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey (Short,1): Unknown-31468
      ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Linear_Meter
      End_Of_Keys.
   End_Of_Geotiff.

PCS = 31468 (name unknown)
GCS: 4314/(unknown)
Ellipsoid: 7004/(unknown) (6377397.16,6356078.96)
Projection Linear Units: 9001/metre (1.000000m)

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left    ( 1547250.000, 5415950.000)
Lower Left    ( 1547250.000,  941650.000)
Upper Right   ( 7186450.000, 5415950.000)
Lower Right   ( 7186450.000,  941650.000)
Center        ( 4366850.000, 3178800.000)
```

From what I understand `ModelTiepointTag` will tell me where in an actual map the pixels it identifies are located so in this case pixel 0,0 should be at 1547250, 5415950 (what values are these exactly?).

`ModelPixelScaleTag` will give me a relation about the images scale in real life. But what exactly do these values mean, and how do I extract a useful value from them (eg this distance in my image is these many meters in real life)?

`Corner Coordinates` is quite easy to understand, but again I dont know what do those values represent. Can I convert them to latitude longitude values?

If the above was too long, then basically what interests me is to be able to understand how can I correlate the values on the image with the actual world values they represent.

Comment: This information: _GeographicTypeGeoKey (Short,1): GCS_DHDN; GeogEllipsoidGeoKey (Short,1): Ellipse_Bessel_1841; ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Linear_Meter_, seem to indicate that the GeoTIFF Coordinate Reference System could be [this](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7133/ogcwkt/), which is a meters projection. This [link](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/listgeo.html) also has explanations about how to extract more information about the GeoTIFF including the latitude and longitude coordinates.

Comment: The GeoTiff specification is http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/spec/geotiffhome.html the spatial reference information is a bit hard to understand - there's *lots* of possible keys that can be stored... although the software you're using says PCS = 31468 (name unknown) it is actually a known spatial reference http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31468/ which may be identified by other software like Esri or QGIS, it's just a little obscure or specific...

Comment: Interestingly enough PCS code does not appear in the list ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/geotiff/tables/horiz_cs.csv but the GCS that it's based on does: 4314,DHDN,,,,Germany - onshore,geographic 2D,6314,8901,North,East,Lat,Long,,9108,,,1995-06-02 00:00:00,,EPSG,, which could be why the projection is parameterized rather that being just an EPSG code.

Comment: The links, especially the one on listgeo are very interesting. What I still cant understand is the transformation between actual distances and image distances. Even if geotifflib can do it, I want to understand how to do it myself.